# iOS7 UISwitch its Event ValueChanged: Calling continuously is this Bug or what..?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5, uiswitch

#### Edit

It's now fixed on [ios7.1](/questions/tagged/ios7.1)

Don't do any tweak to fix it.

#### Edit2

Apparently the same problem happens again in iOS 8.0 and 8.1

#### Edit3

It's now fixed on [ios9.2](/questions/tagged/ios9.2)

Don't do any tweak to fix it.

---

Hi Today i seen in `UISwitch's` Event `ValueChanged:` Calling `continuously`  while i am change to `On` to `Off` or `Off` to On and my finger moved still on right side as well as left side. I atteched GIF image for more clear with NSLog.

[image]

My Value Changed Method is:

```
- (IBAction)changeSwitch:(id)sender{

    if([sender isOn]){
        NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
    } else{
        NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
    }
    
}
```

iOS6 the same code of Switch working Fine as we expectation:

[image]

so can anyone suggest me that call only one time its state On or off. or is this is a bug or what..?

**UPDATE**

Here it is my Demo of it:

[programmatic Add UISwitch](http://ge.tt/4cMlZSw/v/0)

[from XIB adding UISwitch](http://ge.tt/6aG8aSw/v/0)

Comment: have you tried restarting xCode?

Comment: this is not in my xcode this prob in my as well as my frnd's xcode too

Comment: Ya. I too get the same issue when i tried here.. It may be a bug..

Comment: hi @NitinGohel its working fine at my end..

Comment: i've got exactly same problem and i'm going to change UISwitch to just normal button. Cheers!

Comment: It's a bug in uiswitch control

instead of adding extra custom component, I applied both the nnarayann's answer and pre's answer together and it fixes my problem

Comment: No need of doing anything... It's fixed on iOS7.1

Comment: im still getting this bug in iOS7.1 on simulator, havent tried device yet, running xcode 5.1.1

Comment: I am getting same problem with 7.1.2 ipad

Comment: I can see an identical/similar problem with UISwitch in iOS 8.0 and 8.1

Comment: I am having the same experience too in 8.1

Comment: Still here in 9.1. Please file a duplicate of https://openradar.appspot.com/15555929 everyone. This is the only way we're going to get this fixed.

Comment: Having now come across this problem in 9.1 on a device, I find that sometimes the ValueChanged event is not generated at all and the method is not invoked

Comment: Seems that it's back in 9.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got many user that facing same issue so may be this is bug of `UISwitch` so i found just now for temporary solution of it. I Found one `gitHub` custom `KLSwitch` use this for now hope apple will fix this in next update of xCode:-

https://github.com/KieranLafferty/KLSwitch

Answer (score 45):

Please see the following code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 235, 0, 0)];    
    [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:mySwitch];
}

- (void)changeSwitch:(id)sender{
    if([sender isOn]){
        NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
    } else{
        NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for answer as i said i was trying both way and got same result. atlist i knw how to add swtich programmatic as well as from xib sir.

Answer (score 12):

Same bug here. I think I've found a simple workaround. We just have to use a new `BOOL` that stores the previous state of the `UISwitch` and an if statement in our `IBAction` (Value Changed fired) to check that the value of the switch has actually changed.

```
previousValue = FALSE;

[...]

-(IBAction)mySwitchIBAction {
    if(mySwitch.on == previousValue)
        return;
    // resetting the new switch value to the flag
    previousValue = mySwitch.on;
 }
```

No more weird behaviors. Hope it helps.

Comment: this should just say if(mySwitch.on == previousValue)

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `UISwitch`'s `.selected` property to make sure your code only executes once when the value actual changes. I think this is a great solution because it avoids having to subclass or add new properties.

```
 //Add action for `ValueChanged`
 [toggleSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchTwisted:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

 //Handle action
- (void)switchTwisted:(UISwitch *)twistedSwitch
{
    if ([twistedSwitch isOn] && (![twistedSwitch isSelected]))
    {
        [twistedSwitch setSelected:YES];

        //Write code for SwitchON Action
    }
    else if ((![twistedSwitch isOn]) && [twistedSwitch isSelected])
    {
        [twistedSwitch setSelected:NO];

        //Write code for SwitchOFF Action
    }
}
```

And here it is in Swift:

```
func doToggle(switch: UISwitch) {
    if switch.on && !switch.selected {
        switch.selected = true
        // SWITCH ACTUALLY CHANGED -- DO SOMETHING HERE
    } else {
        switch.selected = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I find this one to be simplest.

Comment: +1'd this because it led me to using a similar solution of populating the .tag value when I want to ignore the toggle logic. I need the logic to fire sometimes in both on and off mode so the above wasn't quite sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using so many switch in your app then there is problem to change the code in all places where t
action method of UISwitch is defined.You can make custom switch and handle the events only if value change.

`CustomSwitch.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Care4TodayCustomSwitch : UISwitch
@end
```

`CustomSwitch.m`

```
@interface CustomSwitch(){
    BOOL previousValue;
}
@end

@implementation CustomSwitch



- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        previousValue = self.isOn;
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    previousValue = self.isOn;
    self.exclusiveTouch = YES;
}


- (void)setOn:(BOOL)on animated:(BOOL)animated{

    [super setOn:on animated:animated];
    previousValue = on;
}


-(void)sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target forEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if(previousValue != self.isOn){
        for (id targetForEvent in [self allTargets]) {
            for (id actionForEvent in [self actionsForTarget:targetForEvent forControlEvent:UIControlEventValueChanged]) {
                [super sendAction:NSSelectorFromString(actionForEvent) to:targetForEvent forEvent:event];
            }
        }
        previousValue = self.isOn;
    }
}

@end
```

We are ignoring events if the value is same as changed value.Put CustomSwitch in all the class of UISwitch in storyboard.This will resolve the issue and call target only once when value changed

Comment: This worked for me. It's ideal in that it does not cause extraneous code to be manually added in your implementation files, as it's reusable and hides its implementation inside the class implementation. This is just good design. It would be nice if this answer had more comments though, because I don't really understand why all of the code is there.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. Can you explain the code a little bit more. @codester

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need to react instantly to the switch's value change the following could be a solution:

```
- (IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender {
  [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

  if ([switch isOn]) {
      [self performSelector:@selector(enable) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
  } else {
      [self performSelector:@selector(disable) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm in iOS 11.2. In my situation, it fired 2 events in a row (state: off, swiping: off, 1st event: on, 2nd event: off), so a delay of 0.1s is enough for me and not noticeable to a user.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is still here as of iOS 9.3 beta. If you don't mind the user not being able to drag outside of the switch, I find that using `.TouchUpInside` rather than `.ValueChanged` works reliably.

Answer (score 2):

I am still facing same problem in iOS 9.2

I got solution and posing as it might help others

1. Create count variable to trace number of times method got call

   ```
   int switchMethodCallCount = 0;
   ```
2. Save bool value for switch value

   ```
   bool isSwitchOn = No;
   ```
3. In Switch's value change method perform desire action for first method call only. When switch value again changes set count value andt bool variable value to default

   ```
   - (IBAction)frontCameraCaptureSwitchToggle:(id)sender {



   //This method will be called multiple times if user drags on Switch,
   //But desire action should be perform only on first call of this method


   //1. 'switchMethodCallCount' variable is maintain to check number of calles to method,
   //2. Action is peform for 'switchMethodCallCount = 1' i.e first call
   //3. When switch value change to another state, 'switchMethodCallCount' is reset and desire action perform

   switchMethodCallCount++ ;

   //NSLog(@"Count --> %d", switchMethodCallCount);

   if (switchMethodCallCount == 1) {

   //NSLog(@"**************Perform Acction******************");

   isSwitchOn = frontCameraCaptureSwitch.on

   [self doStuff];

   }
   else
   {
   //NSLog(@"Do not perform");


   if (frontCameraCaptureSwitch.on != isSwitchOn) {

       switchMethodCallCount = 0;

       isSwitchOn = frontCameraCaptureSwitch.on

       //NSLog(@"Count again start");

       //call value change method again 
       [self frontCameraCaptureSwitchToggle:frontCameraCaptureSwitch];


       }
   }


   }
   ```

Comment: I, too, am still facing this issue in 9.2. I implemented your logic, and now it is working as I had intended.

Answer (score 2):

This problem plagues me when I tie the switch to other behaviors. Generally things don't like to go from `on` to `on`. Here's my simple solution:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@parameter (assign) BOOL lastSwitchState;
@parameter (strong) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;
@end

@implementation MyView

// Standard stuff goes here

- (void)mySetupMethodThatsCalledWhenever
{
    [self.mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)switchToggled:(UISwitch *)someSwitch
{
    BOOL newSwitchState = self.mySwitch.on;
    if (newSwitchState == self.lastSwitchState)
    {
        return;
    }
    self.lastSwitchState = newSwitchState;

    // Do your thing
}
```

Just be sure to also set `self.lastSwitchState` every time you manually change `mySwitch.on`! :)

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem is often caused by ValueChanged. You don't need to press the button to cause the function to run. It's not a touch event. Every time you programmatically change the switch to on/off, the value changes and it calls the IBAction function again.

@RoNiT had the right answer with:

Swift

```
func doToggle(switch: UISwitch) {
    if switch.on && !switch.selected {
        switch.selected = true
        // SWITCH ACTUALLY CHANGED -- DO SOMETHING HERE
    } else {
        switch.selected = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.mySwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }
```

This works fine and doesn't calls the selector function again.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()){
    self.switch.isOn = true
}
```