# UISwitch not working if dragged

Tags: ios, xcode, uiswitch

I have a `UISwitch` added as a `contentview` inside a `UITableViewCell`.

The control works only if tapped, but if I try to drag it to the left or the right, the selector function is not called.

Any help?

Comment: What have you added as the target control event ?

Comment: lets see some code. we cannot help if we cannot see code.

Comment: kindly post the code that you tried, which help to answer accordingly.

Comment: UISwitch doesn't send change events when dragging, only when releasing its handle after a drag that would toggle its state.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch_Bool = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
[switch_Bool addTarget:self action:@selector(actionBoolSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:switch_Bool];
```

It works only if i tap my UISwitch, but if i drag it, the function actionBoolSwitch is not called...

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is, you are trying to add a UiSwitch to table view cell.

The very first thing you need to do as a standard practice is to create a subclass of UITableViewCell, add all the components you need and then use it in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

> > take a look at below sample code.

```
  //inside your cell creation block


    UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(add coordinates here...)];
    [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    mySwitch.tag = indexpath.row;
    [cell.contentview addSubview:mySwitch];

  }

  - (void)changeSwitch:(id)sender{

   if([sender isOn])
    {
      NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
    } 
   else
   {
    NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
   }

 }
```

[Also take a look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628310/ios7-uiswitch-its-event-valuechanged-calling-continuously-is-this-bug-or-what)

Answer (score 1):

You may be using `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event.
Use `UIControlEventValueChanged` instead, so your action is called every time the `UISwitch` value changes, no matter what event was the trigger.

Answer (score -2):

**Try this.**

**To find the cell that holds the switch**

```
UISwitch *switchInCell = (UISwitch *)sender;
UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell*) swithInCell.superview;
```

**To find the indexpath of that cell**

```
NSIndexPath * indexpath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell]

 - (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {

         UISwitch *switchInCell = (UISwitch *)sender;
         UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell*) swithInCell.superview;
         NSIndexPath * indexpath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell]
         NSString *strCatID =[[NSString alloc]init];
         strCatID = [self.catIDs objectAtIndex:indexpath];
         NSLog( @"The switch for item %@ is %@",StrCatID, switchInCell.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF" );
        }
```