# UISwitch - detecting end of animation

Tags: ios, ios8, uiswitch

I have an `UISwitch` which is inside of a `UITableViewCell`. I have a target action assigned to switch:

```
[switch addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSwitchColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)changeSwitchColor:(id)sender
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the `changeSwitchColor:` is called before the animation is finished, yet I want to detect when animation has finished, so I can set the `thumbTintColor` property without breaking the animation.

My attempt to detect the animation by using `UIView` `setAnimationDidStopSelector:` method:

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    ...
}
```

But this method is not called on `UISwitch` finishing the animation (I'm not even sure how the animation is made internally).

**How could I detect the finishing state of `UISwitch`?**

Thanks!

Comment: You may find your answer from the other stackoverflow answer link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628310/ios7-uiswitch-its-event-valuechanged-calling-continuously-is-this-bug-or-what

Comment: How exactly would that question answer mine?

Comment: `UISwitch` is a NOT good class. It's hard to override or customize. I think you should override `UIControl` and make your own switch

Comment: I really wanted to avoid making my own switch, I know about `UIControl` of course.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(_:)`.

```
addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged(sender:)), for: [.valueChanged])

@objc private func valueChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { [onChange] in
        onChange?(sender.isOn)
    }
}
```

The documentation says the block is guaranteed to be called even if there are no animations or the animation was removed. It makes it very safe to use.

Comment: Didn't work for me: seems to just run straightaway without waiting for animation of switch to complete

Comment: Maybe this behaviour was different for older iOS version?

Answer (score 1):

**Tomáš** answer using **Swift 4**:

```
settingsSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

@objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        //... animation just finished
    }
}
```