# Interrupt UISwitch dragging action

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiswitch

I was wondering if there was a way to force interrupt an `UISwitch` dragging action? (seems dirty)

The problem:
On value change, my `UISwitch` updates the state and sets `.isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false`, so further taps aren’t processed until async operation complete and state is then updated (unlocking the `UISwitch`).
In the case where the user switches the `UISwitch` by dragging it (tap and hold), it sets `.isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false`, but the user stays in control of the switch while holding the finger, and can then flip the `UISwitch` as much he wants and bypass `.isUserInteractionEnabled`.

When using a random `UISwitch` in one of the iPhone Settings menu, you can also drag and drop a `UISwitch`, but at some point the gesture/drag is cancelled and you lose control over it. I don’t see anything to do that in the public API of `UISwitch`?

Or maybe I shouldn’t use `valueDidChange()`? I don't see another reliable alternative.

Edit: A TL;DR version

The problem is: if the user hold his tap, even by disabling userInteractions he can still move the switch as long as he hold the initial tap.

Comment: I don't get your issue. If the value didn't change surely you wouldn't run the async task? Like only when the user has changed the switch would your run your async and this point lock the switch by disabling interactions? Please provide some code to make this more clear!

Comment: I can't reproduce. In settings, I can drag a switch back and forth as much as I want. Are you testing on device or simulator? Dragging tends to behave differently.

Comment: @AntersBear The issue it stated above: when using a UISwitch, setting `.isUserInteractionEnabled` to false will prevent new tap on the switch, but disabling it while the user is holding the control won't release the hold. So you end up in a situation where the UISwitch.isUserInteractionEnabled IS false, but the user can still switch the UISwitch

Comment: @regina_fallangi Yes I'm aware of that, using device. Take something that starts an async operation, a VPN connection UISwitch for example (can reproduce 100%)
edit: grammar

Comment: Could not reproduce on VPN connection UISwitch -> https://youtu.be/Jdh7Qsrxz9Q

Comment: @regina_fallangi yhea weirdly enough it's as you described here, I should have been more precise: see General > VPN > use the switch there.

The switch doesn't move visually (get locked?) but I can still feel the haptic feedback from the device (there is something weird going on!)

Comment: Look under in the UITableView, there is a cell called `General`, clic that, go to `VPN` after and you'll have a more techy menu

Comment: Still can not reproduce what you are talking about -> https://youtu.be/T3pAELz58qQ

Comment: @regina_fallangi Interesting... I just reproduce the problem here, but can't upload the video as I don't know how to blur some element out of it... 

It doesn't behave the same on my devices, no idea why.

I do the same as you, except that at some point the switch don't move anymore. Could it be a difference in the VPN profiles? I don't think so, because I tried with 3 devices and 4 differents profiles (NordVPN and house made ones), I can reproduce 100%, on all devices, all profiles. Weird. All on ios 11.4

Comment: I can only reproduce when I lift my finger and try to tap again. If I do not lift my finger, I can drag every time. Tried in iPhone X, iPhone SE and iPhone 8S. All on 11.4, fresh install, no special settings.

Comment: You probably want to take a look at this answer, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628310/ios7-uiswitch-its-event-valuechanged-calling-continuously-is-this-bug-or-what

Comment: Thanks for such dedication in testing this little problem @regina_fallangi
I'll try that question thing tomorow as I don't have an XCode available around right now

Comment: @regina_fallangi the above question is not related actually.

The problem is really simple: if the user hold his tap, even by disabling userInteractions he can still move the switch as long as he hold the initial tap